# TabNavigator contents width not equals with TabNavigator itself

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

The content(Here is VBox) is not align with Tab, put it in another way, the content is stretch out one pixel(The red border is wider than the Tab), as show in the following pic:
[image]
***So how to solve the issue?***

code snippet:

```
<mx:Application
        xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        backgroundColor="white"
        >
    <mx:TabNavigator id="tn"
                 width="300"
                 height="300"
                tabWidth="{tn.width/tn.numChildren}"
                borderStyle="solid"
                borderColor="#ff0000"
                backgroundColor="#ffffff"
                paddingTop="0">
            <mx:VBox id="vb1" width="100%" label="Tab 1" backgroundColor="#ffffff">
                <mx:Label text="width:{vb1.width}, height:{vb1.height}" />
            </mx:VBox>
            <mx:VBox id="vb2" width="100%" label="Tab 2" backgroundColor="#00ffff">
                <mx:Label text="width:{vb2.width}, height:{vb2.height}" />
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:TabNavigator>
    </mx:Application>
```

Comment: I'm a little out of touch with `mx` components, but I suppose TabNavigator has a border 1px wide (on each side). So if you want `vb1` to be 300px wide, you may have to make `tn` 302px wide. Or just set vb1's `width` to `100%`.

Comment: @RIAstar, it seems that setting vb1's width to 100% not work, the VBox's width is still 298

Comment: Because `tn`'s width is still 300 I presume: you have to account for the border width and set its width to 302 if you want `vb1` to be 300px wide. (I see it wasn't very clear in my previous comment that you still had to adjust tn's width)

Comment: @RIAstar, you're right. Do you have any opinion about the second issue?

Comment: Ehm, what second issue. I see only one :-/

Comment: @RIAstar, in the TabNavigator, the child is not align with the Tab, as show in the snapshot, you can't see the pic?

Comment: Aha, my bet is you're not calculating the `tabWidth` correctly: I believe the tabs overlap each other by 1px. Try `tabWidth="{(tn.width + 1) / tn.numChildren}"`